# Form Validation PHP / Avoiding injections

Tags: php, mysql, forms, validation

I have created a form (enquiry form) in HTML that posts to the following code:

```
<?php           
if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{
$name = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['name']);
$surname = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['surname']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['email']);
$phone = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['phone']);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['country']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['message']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO contact
       (name, surname, email, phone, country, message)
       VALUES('$name', '$surname', '$email', '$phone', '$country', '$message')";

mysql_select_db($db);
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn )or die(mysql_error());

echo 'Thank you '.$name.' '.$surname.'. Your enquiry has been forwarded to our team. <br><br>Please check you email inbox for further information.<br><br>Return to homepage:<br><br><button class="search" onclick="/">Return to homepage</button>';

mysql_close($conn);
}

?>
```

I am wondering, how I can display errors and stop the form posting when invalid or zero data is entered?

Whilst learning how to create forms on the web, I also heard about SQL injections. Am I protected?

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering how I can display errors and stop the form posting when invalid or zero data is entered.

You have to do the validation after `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`. For example you could check is name is non empty:

```
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $errors[] = 'name must not be empty';
}
```

For more complicated validations such as validating that email is valid, you should take a look at the **[filter extension](http://fr.php.net/filter)**:

```
$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if (!$email) // invalid email
```

And after all your validations:

```
if (!count($errors)) {
    // do the insert here
}
```

You could use a while block to break as soon as you detect an error:

```
while (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $errors = 'name must not be empty';
        break;
    }

    // do the insert here

    break;
}
```

---

> Whilst learning how to create forms on the web, I also heard about sql injections, am I protected?

Yes, as long as you escape anything that you embed in a SQL query (just like you are doing), you are protected.

You should try using **[prepared statements](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)**, this is safer and easier to use.

Comment: ...as long as you escape all the **string values** you embed in a SQL query, not variables.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel Basically, all submitted values are strings. There is a difference between a numeric value (`"123"`) and an integer (`123`). Therefore I find it good practice to cast values for int columns to integers, besides escaping string inputs.

Comment: I mean for the SQL, the only string value is one enclosed in quotes

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php           
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$errors = array();
$name = !empty($_POST['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['name']) : $errors[] = 'Name must not be empty';
$surname = !empty($_POST['name']) ? mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['name']) : $errors[] = 'User Name must not be empty';
$email = !empty($_POST['email']) ? mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['email']) : $errors[] = 'Email must not be empty';
$phone = !empty($_POST['phone']) ? mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['phone']) : $errors[] = 'Phone must not be empty';
$country = !empty($_POST['country']) ? mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['country']) : $errors[] = 'Country must not be empty';
$message = !empty($_POST['message']) ? mysql_real_escape_string((string)$_POST['message'])  : $errors[] = 'Message must not be empty';

if (empty($errors))
{   
if (preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO contact
   (name, surname, email, phone, country, message)
   VALUES('$name', '$surname', '$email', '$phone', '$country', '$message')";

    mysql_select_db($db);
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn )or die(mysql_error());

    echo 'Thank you '.$name.' '.$surname.'. Your enquiry has been forwarded to our team. <br><br>Please check you email inbox for further information.<br><br>Return to homepage:<br><br><button class="search" onclick="/">Return to homepage</button>';

    mysql_close($conn);
}
else {
    echo 'Invalid Email';   
}
}
else
{
foreach ($errors AS $error) 
{
    echo "$error<br />";    
}
}
}
```

?>

Comment: It's a bad practice to sql-escape variables too early. You should not even assign them with the escaped value (and ideally you should use prepared statements).